# SQL Server - How to set Row ID for duplicate or similar content based on insertion first. Select query

Tags: sql-server

Priority is the output column.

The group contains duplicate content.

how can I fix this using SQL query?.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0KmY.png)

Comment: No Group priority
1 ababab 1
2 ababab 1
3 cdcdcdcd 2
4 cdcdcdcd 2
5 efef 3
6 efef 3
7 ababab 1
8 cdcdcdcd 2
9 ababab 1
10 efef 3

Comment: `distinct`? What result are trying to get?

Comment: please do not use picture to display your tables, use plain text or table markdown.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the desired result with this data is to use `Dense_rank()` function like below:

```
select *, dense_rank() over (order by [Group]) as Priority
from tab
order by No
```

For any value, please try the following

```
;with cte as
(   
    select [Group], ROW_NUMBER() over (order by No_min) as rn
    from
    (
        select [Group], min([No]) No_min
        from tab
        group by [Group]
    )t
)
select t.*, x.rn as [Priority]
from cte x
join tab t on t.[Group] = x.[Group]
order by 1
```

Please find the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3060f5e90e6c101a4c20f39cbabe9a89).

Comment: dense_rank() already tried. It ranks Result Based on Characters. i don't want alphabetical order.

Comment: @SandipPatil Please check the updated answer and see if that resolves your issue.